# boost::ptr_vector and find_if

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I have a class:

```
//header file
class CMDatabase
{
    class Try;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Try> TryPtr;
    typedef boost::ptr_vector<Try> TryVector;
    typedef TryVector::iterator TryVectorIterator;

    class Try
    {
        public:
            virtual ~Try();
            virtual bool equal(CMDatabase::TryPtr mySd) = 0;
    };
};

//.cpp file

class TryImpl : public CMDatabase::Try
{
    bool equal(CMDatabase::TryPtr mySd)
    {
        //boost::shared_ptr<ServiceDataImpl> ServiceDataImplPtr;
        //const ServiceDataImplPtr pOtherData = dynamic_cast<const ServiceDataImplPtr>(mySd);

        //ServiceDataImpl *pOtherData = dynamic_cast<ServiceDataImpl *>(mySd.get());
        return true;
    }
};

//Another .cpp file

void UpdateClass::TryFind()
{
    CMDatabase::TryVector defaultTry;
    CMDatabase::TryVector updateTry;

//Code for filling two vectors here....

    for(CMDatabase::TryVectorIterator i = defaultTry.begin(); i != defaultTry.end(); ++i)
    {
       CMDatabase::TryVectorIterator it = find_if(updateTry.begin(), updateTry.end(),bind1st(mem_fun(&CMDatabase::Try::equal), *i));

    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get error:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'initializing' :
>   cannot convert from 'const CMDatabase::Try' to 'CMDatabase::Try
>   *'    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\functional  296

Can anyone pelase tell me what is it that I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Couldn't you put all the code in a <pre><code> block? It would make it much more readable :)

Comment: No need for tags, the markdown syntax supports indentation by 4 spaces for code-blocks. One can also just select the code and hitting the `010` button. @elr

Answer (score 1):

**Just for sake of completeness, the following statement is wrong! Thanks to Matthieu M. to point out my mistake!**

On dereferencing an iterator of the boost pointer container you will get the pure pointer to the element. So you can try to dereference the pure pointer you get through the iterator:

```
CMDatabase::TryVectorIterator it =
  find_if(updateTry.begin(), updateTry.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(&CMDatabase::Try::equal), **i));
```

---

**Where the following is still correct ;)**

Or you can use the the `operator[]` implementation of the `boost::ptr_vector` which will return a reference to the element:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, l = ; defaultTry.size(); ++i) {
  CMDatabase::TryVectorIterator it = std::find_if(
    updateTry.begin(),
    updateTry.end(),
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&CMDatabase::Try::equal), defaultTry[i])
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 This answer appears to be more on the mark with the error described

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. Dereferencing an iterator into a Boost.Pointer Container yields a reference to the object, not a pointer to it, so that you don't have to double dereference. It's part of the goodies of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `equal` method is not `const` qualified.

```
class Try
{
public:
  virtual ~Try();
  virtual bool equal(CMDatabase::TryPtr const& mySd) const = 0;
};

bool TryImpl::equal(CMDatabase::TryPtr const& mySd) const { return true; }
```

Note:

- the `const` added to the method, otherwise it cannot be used on `const` objects
- the `const` added on the pointer: copying `shared_ptr` does cost, because it necessitates incremented a shared counter, and decrementing it afterward.

**EDIT**:

Reminder for the unwary: the Pointer Container library has been designed so that the interface would be as easy to use a possible, and one of the goody is that you don't have to double dereference. This compiles:

```
 boost::ptr_vector<int> vec;
 vec.push_back(new int(3));

 int& i = *vec.begin();
```

Thus, your functor must take a reference, not a pointer :)

Comment: At first I thought this answer had merit but it does not address the invalid conversion from a CMDatabase::Try to a CMDatabase::Try* (pointer)

Comment: There is no such issue. You use a `boost::ptr_vector` for its interface too: `CMDatabase::Try& t = *it`. And that's why the error message doesn't even mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, For soem reason, i could not add comment to previous post, so I am writing it as answer.

I tried both the methods.
First one gives,  illegal indirection.

And for the second one, it gives the same error:
In verbose output, the details are as follows:

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\functional(296) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const CMDatabase::Try' to 'CMDatabase::Try *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
        c:\fta_chk\tools\channel_editor\ivodb\channellistupdate.cpp(103) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::binder1st<_Fn2> std::bind1st,CMDatabase::Try>(const _Fn2 &,const _Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Fn2=std::mem_fun1_t,
            _Result=bool,
            _Ty=CMDatabase::Try,
            _Arg=CMDatabase::TryPtr
        ]

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to comment: it requires 15 points.

Comment: @Matthieu: Users should always be able to comment on their own questions though.

Comment: I know they can comment on their own question, but I am unsure whether they can comment on the responses...

Comment: @Matthieu: Thats what i meant :) The FAQ has a foot-note: *"you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep."*